# How to make PHP and CSS code work together

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm working on a project, using PHP, HTML and CSS code. The problem is when I execute it without CSS code it works, but when I add CSS to it the message "successfully created" will be displayed on the bottom status bar of the webpage! Why does this happen and why won't it be displayed on the page?

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="bg">
    <p><a href = "register.php">Register</a> | <a href="login.php">Login</a></p>
    <h3>Registration Form</h3>
    <form action="register.php" method = "POST">
        Email: <input type = "text" name = "email"><br />
        Username: <input type = "text" name = "user"><br />
        Password: <input type = "password" name = "pass"><br />
        <input type = "submit" value = "Login" name = "submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

This is my PHP code:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost' , 'root' , '', 'website') or die(mysqli_error());
    mysqli_select_db($connection , "website") or die("can not select database");

    if ($connection) {
        $query = mysqli_query($connection ,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$user."'");
        $numOfRows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        if ($numOfRows == 0){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO users( email ,username , password) VALUES('$email', '$user' , '$pass')";
            $result = mysqli_query($connection , $sql);
            if($result) {
                echo "successfully Created";
            } else {
                echo "failure!";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Username already exist!";
        }
    } else {
        echo "can not connect to database";
    }
}
```

This is my CSS code:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.bg {
    background-image: url("SARV.jpg");
    height: 100%; 
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you echo in plain text instead of handling it into your html code. Take a look into your output html.

Comment: sry im kinda new to html , would you help me more ?

Comment: Try to understand how the html is produced. echo "<div id='inpage'>successfully Created</div>" and then according css. But this is no good solution. Just an example